# Is it possible to access JSP style tag values in an angularjs html view?

Tags: angularjs, jsp

Is it possible to access JSP style tag values in an angularjs html view? For example, can I get the ‘principal.firstName’ value in the browser, from the tag below? Is there an Angularjs way to do this?

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.firstName"/>
```

… or, do I need to access this serverside, and return in JSON? If I do need to access it server side, could you point me to an example, everything I have found just shows how to get principal.getName().

I’m trying to convert our jsp pages to be html.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do essentially the same thing by creating a JSON object, the values of which were these JSP variables which would be filled in by the server.  This JSON object can be a separate page that is accessed by Angular using an `$http.get()` function.

Like this:

```
{'mySettings': {
    'userID': <%=user.ID%>,
    'firstName': '<%=user.first_name%>',
    'lastName': '<%=user.last_name%>'
}}
```

The server will process the `<%=whatever%>` directives and replace them with actual data.  Then your AngularJS code will issue an http.get to pull in this JSON and use it on the client.

Comment: Seems like I would still need to use .jsp pages with this approach? Really trying to not use .jsp pages.... I'd like to be able to access the values in java if not in .js file.

Comment: You'll need to use some server-side technology to read the values that are (presumably) coming from a database into the JSP pages.  You can do it without using JSP but you'll need a different server-side technology such as Node or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can create directive, that will read your attribute from *sec:authentication* tag and pass it on variable.

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/0vzcr5x8/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    this.firstName = 1;
  })
  .directive("myProperty", function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        val: "=myProperty"
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.val = attr.property;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <sec:authentication my-property="vm.firstName" property="principal.firstName" />{{vm.firstName}}
    <div my-property="vm.name" property="john doe"></div>{{vm.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code looks good, but it (to me) looks like the view would be in a jsp file, and still requires JSP tags. I'm trying to avoid JSPs all together. Thanks!

Comment: Then you have to ask a different question. How to use the JSP tags to HTML page. Because you are wondering how to use the JSP tag in HTML pages. Angular here is irrelevant.

Comment: My question wasn't correct. I really wanted to avoid the JSP tags all together. I really should have asked how to get those user principal values server side, so I could return them to front end.